# Property 'delegate' not found on object 'AddEventViewController'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, eventkit

With the help of the Developer Library, I am trying to work with the EventKit and EventKitUI Frameworks. I've hit a very early roadblock. I have copied and pasted [code from the library found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3). I have added a view controller called 'AddEventViewController' a button to the Navigation Bar in my ViewController and I am using this code to invoke it.

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
AddEventViewController *addController = [[AddEventViewController alloc]
                                          init];
addController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                                    initWithRootViewController:addController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

}

The error shows on line: `addController.delegate = self;`

This code is copied straight from the Library. I am using Xcode 4.2 and a Storyboard if that might help.

UPDATE:
This is AddEventViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AddEventViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

You're going to tell me I created this ViewController incorrectly? Please explain why just not "how" if you'd be so nice?

Comment: Are you sure your `AddEventViewController` actually has `delegate` property? Please post it's declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see how Apple's example here has likely confused you here. First, download the full source for [iPhoneCoreDataRecipes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html) (or at least reference it while trying to understand this code).

To really understand what's going on here, you need to read on down to the section called "Dismissing a Presented View Controller" and then follow the link to "Use a Delegation to Communicate With Other Controllers." ("a Delegation?" Very strange....)

So here's what's going on. The presented view has a "delegate" which is the object it's supposed to tell "interesting" things to. In this case, "interesting" things are "hey, I added a recipe!" To achieve this, the delegate implements a protocol, which just means it promises to implement some methods. In this case, the required method is `recipeAddViewController:didAddRecipe:`.

`AddViewController` has a `delegate` property like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <RecipeAddDelegate> delegate;
```

That just means that the delegate must conform to the named protocol. The delegate itself indicates that it does so in its interface:

```
@interface RecipeListTableViewController : UITableViewController <RecipeAddDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
```

Note that this is marked `assign` for reasons @Yuras explains. But if you're writing new code targeted at iOS 5, you should use `weak` instead of `assign`. `weak` properties are automatically set to `nil` if their referenced object is deallocated. It's just safer that way. No dangling pointers.

Comment: You just stole the correct answer from Yuras... Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In Objective-C any property you are using should be declared somewhere. Any properties, that are declared in parent class (`UIViewController` in your case) are inherited by all the derived classes (`AddEventViewController` in your case).

`AddEventViewController` inherits `UIViewController`, but the `delegate` property is not declared neither in the first, nor in the second. That is why compiler is not happy.

You should declare it. Something like the next:

```
@interface AddEventViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;  

@end

@implementation AddEventViewController

@synthesize delegate;

@end
```

Delegates are usually declared with `assign` attribute to prevent circle retains (e.g. `A` retains `B` and `B` retains `A`)

Comment: Also it could be a good idea to read header files related to `UITableViewController`, `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` from iOS SDK to take an idea how to design classes with delegates.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Now I've got to go back and really understand what the delegate is. I definitely "missed" that lesson over the past month.